# SQLite Android JOIN query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to fetch the records from SQLite database from 3 Tables.

**Tables Structure**
1. tb_contacts Table
It contains the contact information like id, name and email.

```
contact_id | contact_name | contact_email
---------- | ------------ | ------------------
1          | Deepak       | deepak@yopmail.com
---------- | ------------ | ------------------
2          | Shivam       | shivam@yopmail.com
```

2. tb_numbers Table
It contains the phone number of each contact

```
id | contact_id | contact_phone
---| ---------- | ------------
1  | 1          | 123456789      
---| ---------- | ------------
2  | 1          | 789456123     
---| ---------- | ------------
3  | 2          | 456123654      
---| ---------- | ------------
4  | 2          | 698521473
```

3. tb_deleted table status
this table conatins the status of contact whether it is deleted or not with user_id. If this table contains the row of contact with particular user_id, it means the contact has deleted for that user, otherwise not.

```
id | contact_id | user_id
---| ---------- | --------
1  | 1          | 22201      
---| ---------- | --------
2  | 1          | 22202     
---| ---------- | --------
3  | 2          | 22201
```

**What i want**
1. Suppose user with user_id **22201**. It will get all the contacts like

```
contact_id | contact_name | contact_email      | contact_phone | deleted
---------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------- | -------
1          | Deepak       | deepak@yopmail.com | 123456789     | 1
---------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------- | -------
1          | Deepak       | deepak@yopmail.com | 789456123     | 1
---------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------- | -------
2          | Shivam       | shivam@yopmail.com | 456123654     | 1
---------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------- | -------
2          | Shivam       | shivam@yopmail.com | 698521473     | 1
```

2. Now user with user_id **22202**.

```
contact_id | contact_name | contact_email      | contact_phone | deleted
---------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------- | -------
1          | Deepak       | deepak@yopmail.com | 123456789     | 1
---------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------- | -------
1          | Deepak       | deepak@yopmail.com | 789456123     | 1
---------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------- | -------
2          | Shivam       | shivam@yopmail.com | 456123654     | 0
---------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------- | -------
2          | Shivam       | shivam@yopmail.com | 698521473     | 0
```

**What i have tried**

```
SELECT tb_contacts.contact_id, tb_contacts.contact_name, tb_contacts.contact_email, tb_numbers.contact_phone from tb_contacts join tb_numbers on tb_contacts.contact_id = tb_numbers.contact_id left join tb_deleted on tb_contacts.contact_id = tb_deleted.contact_id;
```

It is providing me the records of each contact with deleted status but without user_id. How can i get the required data with condition of user_id. I have used `WHERE` clause but with this, it only provide the records of those contacts for which there is a entry in `tb_deleted` table.
What is the best way or solution so that i can get the required data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look up whether the user is deleted, use a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
SELECT contact_id,
       contact_name,
       contact_email,
       contact_phone,
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM tb_deleted
               WHERE contact_id = tb_contacts.contact_id
                 AND user_id    = 22201
              ) AS deleted
FROM      tb_contacts
LEFT JOIN tb_numbers USING (contact_id);
```

Comment: Hi CL., It works perfectally. Well is there any way to get the list of contacts having one row of each contact with multiple phone numbers not with one row of each contact having one phone number?

Comment: With grouping and [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat), but that would be a different question.

Comment: Thanks. With group_concat(),i'm able to get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

try with this query:

```
SELECT tb_contacts.*, contact_phone, deleted FROM(
SELECT tb_numbers.contact_id, tb_numbers.contact_phone, COUNT(tb_deleted2.user_id) as deleted FROM tb_numbers
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tb_deleted.user_id FROM tb_deleted) as tb_deleted
LEFT JOIN tb_deleted as tb_deleted2 ON tb_numbers.contact_id = tb_deleted2.contact_id and 
tb_deleted.user_id = tb_deleted2.user_id AND tb_deleted2.user_id = '22201'
group by tb_numbers.contact_id, tb_numbers.contact_phone) as crossed_join
LEFT JOIN tb_contacts ON  tb_contacts.contact_id = crossed_join.contact_id
```

Result:

[image]

using cross join might slow things down, you can try using the SELECT ..., (Select COUNT(*) FROM tb_deleted WHERE contact_id = deleted_contact_id and deleted_user_id = '2201') as deleted FROM ..... not sure if the speed is faster or slower though

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing a query like this:

```
SELECT tb_contacts.contact_id, tb_contacts.contact_name, tb_contacts.contact_email, tb_numbers.contact_phone,
FROM tb_contacts
JOIN tb_numbers ON tb_contacts.contact_id = tb_numbers.contact_id
WHERE tb_contacts.contact_id NOT IN (
   SELECT tb_deleted.contact_id from tb_deleted WHERE tb_deleted.user_id = user_id
);
```